# When a ViewContainerRef is injected into a directive what element is it bound to?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When a `ViewContainerRef` is injected into a directive what element is it bound to?

For example if we have a template:

```
template `<div><span vcdirective></span></div>`
```

And the constructor for the `vcdirective` looks like this:

```
  constructor(vc: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
```

Is the element that the `vc:ViewContainerRef` is bound to the `span` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will bind to span element. If you console the vc in constructor, you will see ViewContainerRef object, check the element property of it, you will find **span** there. But when you will attach the view in the container, it will be appended next to span instead of being inserted inside it and span will be left hanging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's bound to span. `ViewContainerRef` represents a container where one or more views can be attached. We can use its methods such as `createEmbeddedView()` and `createComponent()`. `ViewContainerRef` is used to build **dynamic components**.

Answer (score 0):

please check this to better understand.  it is a placeholder that can attach to another elemetent.   check https://netbasal.com/angular-2-understanding-viewcontainerref-acc183f3b682

something like:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'vcr',
  template: `
    <template #tpl>
      <h1>ViewContainerRef</h1>
    </template>
  `,
})
export class VcrComponent {
  @ViewChild('tpl') tpl;
  constructor(private _vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using constructor injection on the component the `ViewContainerRef` is bound to the host element, which in this case will be the `vcr` selector IIUC.